# How to create a message with message stack when user becomes a member of a group module group?

Tags: 8, group, message-subscribe

Hi currently I try to code a custom module for notification based on [message stack module](https://drupal.org/project/message).

Now I'm searching for the event or hook to perform some custom code when the user becomes a member of a [group](https://drupal.org/project/group).

I want to create a message based on the message stack like "the user John Doe became a member of group xxx. Visit group xxx."

Unfortunately I didn't found something like that in the module docs, so I ask here.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the membership relationship is stored as a `GroupContent` entity, so in theory you would use something like [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/9.1.x)as your event:

```
function MODULE_group_content_insert(\Drupal\group\Entity\GroupContentInterface $group_content) {
  // This will fire for all types of group content so make sure to filter
  if ($group_content->getContentPlugin()->getPluginId() == 'group_membership') {
    $account = $group_content->getEntity();
    $group = $group_content->getGroup();    
    // Create the message
  }
}
```

This is untested so may need tweaking, but it should be close enough to get going.